# Http response code for invalid/missed host name

Tags: http, dns

let say I have ip `1.2.3.4` and I mapped it to the following names

```
folk.dude.cool
homie.dude.cool
bro.dude.cool
pal.dude.cool
buddy.dude.cool
```

I check the `Host` header value in my http server to forward the request to the related module.

Now what http response code should I respond(`400?`, `502?`) to client when the value with `Host` header is missed or invalid? I note I like to show a error page rather to forward to a default name.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a malformed message, thus 400.

Answer (score 5):

Julian is correct:

[RFC 2616 - 14.23 Host](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#14.23)

> ... A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
>   messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name
>   for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be
>   given with an empty value. An HTTP/1.1 proxy MUST ensure that any
>   request message it forwards does contain an appropriate Host header
>   field that identifies the service being requested by the proxy. All
>   Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header
>   field.

When you've got protocol questions, the RFCs are a little dry to read, but very informative.